# Having trouble booting Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: boot, grub2

I've recently taken the plunge to leave Windows completely behind me and explore Linux. I decided to start with Ubuntu to get the hang of it all, however, I seem to have run into a problem that I can't seem to find the answer to - Ubuntu will not load on the first occasion of pressing the power button or after using the restart option.

I put Ubuntu on my laptop on Saturday Night, taking the option to erase Windows and just use Ubuntu 15.10 which I booted from a live-USB. Everything seemed to go well and initial reboot went well.

However, I noticed on Sunday that things were not as well as they seemed and have been searching for an answer since then. When I power up my laptop, it goes to the GRUB menu, to which I press enter for Ubuntu, the screen flickers and then the whole computer grinds to halt and does nothing on a black screen.

At this point, if I press the power button off then on, it takes me back to the GRUB menu and again, I press enter for Ubuntu and then it will run. I currently have UEFI on my laptop as it was shipped with Win8 and I wondered if it was a possible cause of the problems.

I've run the boot repair app in USB live mode, and this is the URL http://paste.ubuntu.com/15073507

I would be grateful for any help in solving this issues it is already presented some problems when it comes to rebooting for updates.

~Novotose

Comment: what is the full configuration of your system? Why it is formatted as 'ext2'?

Comment: Hi @Ashu my laptop is a HP Pavillion g6 running on AMD A10-4200M processor, with Ubuntu 15.10 installed as the sole operating sytem. With regards to ext2, I don't know why it is formatted that why. I did the full install as per my USB-live stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must have been something completely going wrong.
There is no Ubuntu operating system to be seen on the disk.
The installation setup of your disk is not configured properly.

You really should reinstall Ubuntu.
I try to make it as easy as possible :

Boot from Ubuntu installation media.
Select 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.

Open GParted and delete all partitions.
Right-click the partitions - select delete.
Click on Apply to complete the deletion.

Create a new partition - format it with fat32 - I suggest a size of about 100 MB.
Create a new partition - format it with swap - I suggest a size matching your RAM.
Create a new partition - format it with ext4 - I suggest to use the rest of free space.

On the desktop click Install Ubuntu - choose Something else.
Select the ext4 partition you had created for Ubuntu before.
Select **/** as mount point and `ext4` file system for formatting.

Comment: I have to confess that I couldn't get Ubuntu to load at all, in the end, I loaded Mint, to see if that made any difference, and it seems to be running fine, and booting properly. That said, brilliant answer, and I gave it a good shot but I got the same result three times.